# XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer alternate API in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-core

We have a code that uses the XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer to generate the assemblies. Here is the sample reference:

```
                 XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(
                        types.ToArray(),
                        xmlMapping.ToArray(),
                        parameters);
```

Returns an assembly that contains typed serializers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.generateserializer?view=netframework-4.8#system-xml-serialization-xmlserializer-generateserializer(system-type()-system-xml-serialization-xmlmapping()-system-codedom-compiler-compilerparameters)

Using the above API in the .NET framework code.

As we are now moving to .NET Core looking for equivalent api or alternate mechanism to do the above.

please provide suggestions on how to support the same.

Comment: `XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(Type[]? types, XmlMapping[] mappings, Stream stream)` is actually present in the [.NET Core source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.16/src/libraries/System.Private.Xml/src/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs#L660), it's just **internal**.  If you feel brave, you could call it using reflection.  That seems to be what the SGen itself does, from its [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.16/src/libraries/Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator/src/Sgen.cs#L365).

Comment: You could also install SGen as shown in the [answer by Kirill Polishchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76033770/3744182) and invoke it directly using its [command line arguments](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.16/src/libraries/Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator/src/Sgen.cs#L495).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator).
Simply install this nuget package, edit you `.csproj` file and add this line:

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator" Version="1.0.0" />
```

For more info see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/xml-serializer-generator