# XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer alternate in NetCore

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-core

We use `XmlSerializer` in our code to generate temporary assemblies containing serializers. These asesemblies are then cached, which ensure that resource consumption is low.

Our application is in .NET Framework, and the code we are using currently is -

```
 XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(
                        types.ToArray(),
                        xmlMapping.ToArray(),
                        parameters);
```

We are looking to move our code to .NET core, and I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76011283/xmlserializer-generateserializer-alternate-api-in-net-core), which listed the use of [Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator) package.

While trying to integrate it, I found that there is no constructor/method, which would take both type and xml mapping as argument.

Our net framework code also uses `CompilerParameters` class, present in `System.CodeDom` (which is the third argument to the call, named `parameters`).

Is there an equivalent way to achieve the net framework functionality using the net core package?

Comment: The source code for 4.8 is here and you can create you on class based on this code : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializationILGen.cs,a7d70ee48110a1e9

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator` nuget package for that.  That package will install a CLI tool that can automatically generate serializer DLLs for your types, so no need anymore to call the `GenerateSerializer` method.
You will need to add an extra line in your `.csproj` file to enable automatic running of the CLI tool during builds.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

More info in the [Using Microsoft XML Serializer Generator on .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/xml-serializer-generator) page on Microsoft Learn.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I am trying to get the build working, currently hitting some error. I had a follow up question though -

I see in the sample app that in the link that you mentioned, that we are still writing the following line -
  
----
`var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));`
----
Since in our .NET Framework application, we pass `xmlMappings` as well, will the new NetCore code take care of this? If not, then I might not be able to use it for the migration.

Comment: The `XmlSerializer` type has a static `FromMappings` method that creates a serializer from an array of `XmlMappings`.  [Link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.frommappings?view=net-6.0)